# Stereo vision with raspberry

Tags: camera

Is there a stereo camera module that would work with raspberry?  Did anyone try to do synced video with raspberry in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RPi compute module (note: *not* the regular RPi) has two CSI camera ports, and [implements stereoscopic capture](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=85012). On a regular RPi, however, you'd need to resort to a couple of USB webcams (preferably ones that implement video compression themselves to save the CPU doing any work). Unfortunately, without some means of syncing them externally they'd gradually drift, and I'm not currently aware of any mechanism to synchronize USB webcams.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.  Do you know what is the acceptable time diff in between the captures for the stereo to work? Do you think it is possible to achieve this in software?

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to sync the compute modules cameras in hardware?

Comment: As I understand it, on the compute module if the cameras are initialised for stereoscopic use they are synchronised in hardware. I don't know how close the sync has to be for stereoscopic use, but I'd guess anything beyond a couple of frames would look very strange indeed!